# Would like to just display 3 rows from mySQL result in python

Tags: python, mysql

So right now I have a query that returns about 20 rows.
I do need these later

```
cur.execute(query)

for rows in cur.fetchall():
    print(rows)

cur.close()
conn.close()
```

How could I write the for loop to just write row in range 1-3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use slice notation to get the first three items from rows. http://www.pythoncentral.io/how-to-slice-listsarrays-and-tuples-in-python/

```
for row in cur.fetchall()[:3]:
    print row
```

Comment: It is worth mentioning that it's probably more efficient to use a method instead of fetchall() that just returns 3 rows and/or make sure your query has a LIMIT clause. Because this code fetches all the rows, then returns the first 3 returned, it doesn't just fetch 3 rows.

Answer (score 0):

```
cur.execute(query)

var loop_count = 0 
for rows in cur.fetchall():
   if loop_count == 3:
     break 
   print(rows)
   loop_count = loop_count+1

cur.close()
conn.close()
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. this is very basic...i wrote :)